# How to make git ignore temporary files created by MS Office (starting with ~$)

Tags: git, gitignore

My git repo includes MS Office files (Word, PPT, & Excel), each time I open one of them a temporary file starting with `~$<file-name>` is created.

I tried adding `*/~$*` to the `.gitignore` file, but it still does not work; the temporary file still pops up in the change list shows that there are untracked changes all the time. I had to close all office files to know that my repo is up-to-date.

How to solve this problem? Is there a special syntax for `.gitignore` for such files?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To ignore any file starting with `~$`, use the pattern:

```
~$*
```

Nothing more is needed.

Comment: There are a lot of sub-directories in the repo, the documents can be in any one of them, not just in the root of the tree.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac: Unless a pattern is *anchored*, it applies to all sub-directories. `~$*` is un-anchored. (Anchored is not a Git term, I borrowed it from regular expression theory.)

Comment: You used `*/~$*`, which *is* anchored and applies only to files in one level of subdirectory of the top level. So a top level file `~$foo` won't be suppressed, nor will `a/b/~$foo`; `a/~$foo` and `b/~$foo` will be suppressed. Note that any file that is already *tracked* is not affected either. Note: `**/~$*` should work according to the descripton of `**`, but I've seen this require at least one level of subdirectory too.

Comment: Even using the *un-anchored* version is not working for me, @torek.

Comment: Make sure there are no invisible characters (zero-width spaces like byte order marks) in the file. Make sure the file itself is stored as UTF-8, not UTF-16.

Comment: Does `git status` show the files as untracked or modified?

Comment: `git status` returns the file (`new file:   documents/project_documents/~$<filename>`) in changes to be committed section.

Comment: It worked! I closed all office documents, committed all my changes, and then opened it again, then poof, it's gone. Thanks a lot for your time 1615903 and @torek.

Comment: The `new file: ...` in `changes to be committed` means it's already tracked, and ready to go into a new commit. You might want to make sure it didn't go into the commit you made.

Comment: Try `~$*.doc*` in .gitignore file, which is coming from [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Global/MicrosoftOffice.gitignore).