# .tfignore Office temporary files

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, version-control, tfignore

I'm having trouble ignoring the temporary files created by MS-Office, especially the ones from Excel.

The file is generated when you open some Excel file which is under version control and starts with ~$. It will instant be added to the included changes.

To prevent this I want to exclude this files using .tfignore but it does not work.

[image: Example of temporary xlsx file]

I added ~*.xlsx to my .tfignore file. But as mentioned it does not work.

[image: sample .tfignore]

Anybody out there who can help me?

Comment: Does a wider pattern (`~$*`) work, like in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61811849/274535

Comment: @YanSklyarenko But I can not mark this as accepted answer because you worte only a comment...

Comment: That's fine - it was only a guess, I wasn't sure at all. Great that it works for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~$* works just fine. Thanks to @YanSklyarenko